# Can I get UK visa appointment fees refund before my appointment date?

Tags: visas, uk, refunds, application-status

I have taken appointment for my UK travel visa one week from now. But I want to cancel my UK trip. Can I claim refund for appointment fees paid on appointment cancellation?

Answer (score 4):

Presuming you have applied for a visa outside of the UK, the relevant information regarding refunds is available [here](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/Home/ViewFAQ).

**What is the visa fee refund policy?**

> We will only refund your visa fee
>   if you withdraw your application in writing, using the refund request
>   form on visa4UK, before biometrics are submitted and within 3 months
>   and 7 days of the date the application was paid for. Visa fees for
>   applications where submission of biometric information is not required
>   will only be considered for refund where the written notification of
>   withdrawal is received before the physical applications have been
>   either accepted at the visa application centre or received directly at
>   the Visa section. You will not be entitled to a refund if your
>   application is granted for a shorter time period than the period you
>   applied for.

It does not look likely that you will be eligible for a refund for an application for which you already have an appointment.

Comment: +1, but I think in this case 'appointment' means biometric enrolment at the VFS.

Comment: I see. Ideally the poster should provide further information regarding their application and their residency. VFS global in India (though the OP previously posted about travel from Dubai) has a refund policy here: https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/disclaimer.html#2 which may or may not be applicable.

Comment: Read carefully! That's not about a refund of the application fee.  It's about getting a refund of the 'premium services' they offer. Refunds of an application fee can only be issued by a consulate per the link in your answer :) And the end-user needs to click an item in their account at visa4uk.  So yeah, the critical question is whether or not they have submitted their biometrics (which is typically done at the 'appointment').

Comment: Thanks for that info. I yetserday cancelled my visa appointment. And you know what now its now allowing me to claim refund. When i go to refund request and type my reason, its now allowing me to proceed further. Its taking me to a grey cell which is payment date cell and its showing the current date. And not allowing me to edit it. can someone please help what i should do? I have already cancelled appointment :(

Comment: If this is visa4uk.fco.gov.uk, there is a contact-us link at the top right which should allow you to send an "email" with your issue detailed.